# Nested Backbone View only rendering once

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, view

I am using backbone in a little web app I am developing for a bit of fun, but I am stumped with an issue I have come across with Backbone Views.

When I loaded a nested view into a dynamic view, the nested view will only load the first time it is navigated to, and all of my attempts to load that view again have failed.

An example of this can be found at the link below. After navigating to `#profile` using the button on the left hand side, clicking on the `Show Details` button will navigate to `#profile/view`. This will render the nested view onto the screen. However, navigating away and back again in any combination of routes causes the nested view to no longer continue to render.

Here is a link to the live code: http://onbb.co/app/#dashboard

I have build two methods called `mountView()` and `unMountView()` which are responsible for the rendering and clearing up of the views. 
These can be found in `client/js/packages/router/route.js from line 68 onwards`.

I am loading a root view on the app's initialisation.
This can be seen in `client/js/init.js on line 100` where I call `rootRoute.mountView()`.

All other subsequent views are loaded dynamically within the `handleRoute()` method on `line 8 of client/js/packages/router/router.js`.

Here is the source code for the `handleRoute()` method.

```
/**
* handleRoute - takes the current hash string and determines which route(s) to load
*
* @ param string splat - the current hash string
*/

var handleRoute = function(splat) {
    var self = this;
    self._requestedRouteString = splat;
    self._currentRouteString = self.getCurrentStack().join('/');

    //Check that the requested hash string is different from the current route
    if(self._requestedRouteString !== self._currentRouteString) {

        //Break down the hash string into an array
        var parts = self._requestedRouteString.split('/');
        log('Route Stack Requested:', parts);

        //If there is a current route...
        if(self.getCurrentStack()) {
            //Reverse the array elements
            var routeStack = self.getCurrentStack().reverse();

            //For each section of the current route stack
            for(var j = 0; j < routeStack.length; j++) {
                log('Unmounting route:', routeStack[j].getId());

                //Unmount the view associated with the route
                routeStack[j].unMountView();
            }

            //Now that the current views have all been unmounted, clear the current route stack array.
            self._currentRouteStack = [];
        }

        //As the rootRoute is already loaded elsewhere, declare it as the first element of the array
        var requestedRoutes = ['rootRoute'],
            routeModule = '';

        //for each of the routes requested
        for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {

            //Format the module name from the hash string to camel case.
            if(i > 0) {
                routeModule += '-';
            }
            routeModule += parts[i];

            var camelCase = routeModule.toLowerCase().replace(/-(.)/g, function(match, group1) {
                return group1.toUpperCase();
            });

            //Add the string of the route's module name to the requestedRoutes array
            requestedRoutes.push(camelCase + 'Route');
        }

        //for each of the modules declared.
        for(var k = 0; k < requestedRoutes.length; k++) {

            var routes = [],
                iteration = 0;

            //Load the route module using RequireJS
            require([
                requestedRoutes[k]
            ], function(route) {

                //Build up an array of the Route objects
                routes.push(route);

                if(routes.length > 1) {

                    var parent = routes[iteration-1],
                        child = routes[iteration];

                    //for each of the children declared in the parent route...
                    for(var l = 0; l < parent.getChildren().length; l++) {

                        //Check if the child route module matches the permitted modules allowed by the parent 
                        if(child.getId() == parent.getChildren()[l]) {
                            log('Mounting route:', child.getId());

                            //mount the child view to the parent view
                            child.mountView();
                            //Add the child route to the self._currentRouteStack variable, for the next request.
                            self.addViewToStack(child);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                iteration++;
            });
        }
    } else {

        log('Requested Route was identical to Current Route.');
    }
};
```

Comment: you can post your source code to review?

Comment: I've added the source code to the handle route method now.